# How can I insert element using DOM JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

This code only works on some consoles...

I would like a div to appear before the button when clicked, using only DOM.

How can I fix this code????

````
<html>
    <body>
        <div id ='div'>
        <button id = 'button'>click me!</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            var button = document.getElementById('button');
            var div = document.getElementById('div');
            var appearingDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var appearingDivText = document.createTextNode("Hi how are you? Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?Hi how are you?");
            
            appearingDiv.appendChild(appearingDivText);
            
            button.addEventListener('click',buttonClicked);
            
            function buttonClicked(){
                div.insertBefore(appearingDiv,button);
            }   
                
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Second one: pass two arguments?

Comment: I believe you may just have a typo: `insertBefore('newDiv, oldDiv');` You are passing in a string, remove the single quotes around `newDiv, oldDiv` -> `insertBefore(newDiv, oldDiv);`

Comment: Yes you're totally right! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @beginnerJavaScript You're welcome. Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 1):

***insertBefore*** method takes two parameters ['reference'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) but you are only passing one parameter.

Solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="old">This is paragraph 1</div>
    </div>



    <script>
        //New Element
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var newDivText = document.createTextNode('this is a new div!');
        newDiv.appendChild(newDivText);
        //Add to header div
        var container = document.querySelector('div.header');
        var oldDiv = document.querySelector('div.old');
        container.insertBefore(newDiv, oldDiv);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a typo: insertBefore('newDiv, oldDiv'); You are passing in a string, remove the single quotes around newDiv, oldDiv -> insertBefore(newDiv, oldDiv); – Ryan Wilson

Comment: I think you can just delete your question. A problem caused by a `typo` is most likely of no use to the community. That is why I voted to close this question.